# How to add new custom meta property in nextjs app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have nextjs 13.4 version application. I am using app router system. In server component of a page I used generateMetadata to get head meta data. In app router we can't use Head from 'next/head'. generateMetadata working fine for me. I have code:

```
export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  
  return {
    title: 'Modern Furniture Crafted with Elegance',
    description:
      'Experience the beauty and craftsmanship. Buy furniture for your home online.',
    viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes',
    appleWebApp: { capable: true },
    openGraph: {
      title: 'Modern Furniture Crafted with Elegance',
      description:
        'Experience the beauty and craftsmanship. Buy furniture for your home online.',
    },
  };
}
```

Now I want to add some new property, I want this :
`<meta property="product:brand" content="Facebook">` in head using generateMetadata. If I use other property of generateMetadata, I got `<meta name="product:brand" content="Facebook">`, see in meta tag there is name field but i want property field `"product:brand"`.

How can i add this meta tag.

Comment: What did you add and what did you got ? Please clarify.

Comment: Please check this hope it helps
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#other

Comment: @psudo I only add 
```other: {
      product: 'Facebook',
    },``` 
I got ```<meta name="product" content="Facebook">```  but instead of name 'product' in meta tag I need 'property' like: ```<meta property="product" content="Facebook">```